# Spring validation not picking messages from message.properties

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

```
This is my project structure.

MySpringVAlidation
  -src/main/java
      -com.myproject.controllers
          -SearchCustomerController.java
      -com.myproject.model
          -SearchCustomer.java
      -applicationContext.xml
      -messages_en_US.properties
  -src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
   -mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
   -web.xml
  -src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views
      -AddModifyCustomer.jsp


messages_en_US.properties ( properties file has custom messages)
==========================
NotEmpty.SearchCustomerForm.custId = Customer Id  must be 7 characters.

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml  (dispatcher has Spring configurations)
===========================
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename">
        <value>messages_en_US.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>


SearchCustomer.java  
======================-==========================================================

    @NotEmpty
    @XmlAttribute(name="CustomerID")
    public String getCustId() {
        return custId;
    }

SearchCustomerController.java 
=================================
@RequestMapping(value="/searchCustomer" , method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String processAdd( @ModelAttribute("searchCustomerForm") @Valid SearchCustomer sCust, 
            BindingResult result,   Map<String, Object> model, HttpSession session ) throws IOException, JMSException { 
        sCust.setOrganizationCode("SUPPLY");
        //System.out.println("Session ID:"+session.getId());
        System.out.println("Errors :- "+result.hasErrors()+result.getAllErrors());
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            Customer customerForm = new Customer();
            model.put("customerForm", customerForm);
            return "AddModifyCustomer";
        }else{
                postSearchRequest.postMessage(sCust, "SearchCustomer.xml",session.getId());     
                //For the second tab
                        Customer customerForm = new Customer();
                        model.put("customerForm", customerForm);

                return "AddModifyCustomer";
        }
    }

AddModifyCustomer.jsp
=====================

<form:form action="searchCustomer" method="post" commandName="searchCustomerForm">                              
<label style="padding-right: .25em;width: 7em;text-align: right;float: left;">
Customer ID : </label><form:input id="custId" path="custId" />

 <input style="float:center;" type="submit" name="Search" id="Search" value="Search" />&nbsp; <button type="button" name="add" id="add" value="add">add</button>    
 <br/><form:errors path="custId"></form:errors>                     
<form:hidden path="organizationCode" />        
</form:form>
```

Expected result when i click on the search customer without providing any input :
    `Customer` Id  must be `7` characters.
    Actual Result : - `may not be empty`
    Note the `@NotEmpty`, even i have tried doing `@NotEmpty(message="{NotEmpty.SearchCustomerForm.custId}")`  , but still getting the same result

```
The messages in properties file is not get picked up. Its always showing default messages. Where am i going wrong?
```

Comment: Are you using maven and a default maven structure?

Comment: yes. I am using maven.

Comment: initially i was getting a warning unable to find the bundle messages_en_US.properties. So i have kept it in my src/main/java folder instead of src/main/webapp/resources

Comment: if i print the error, i get the following message : true[Field error in object 'searchCustomerForm' on field 'custId': rejected value []; codes [NotEmpty.searchCustomerForm.custId,NotEmpty.custId,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [searchCustomerForm.custId,custId]; arguments []; default message [custId]]; default message [may not be empty]]

Comment: Try to move your properties file to /src/main/resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is SearchCustomer, but in your properties file you are using SearchCustomerForm.

Try `NotEmpty.SearchCustomer.custId = Customer Id  must be 7 characters.`

The syntax for the message should be:

```
[Constraint].[Class name].[Property]=[Message]
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error even if i change the Syntax to NotEmpty.SearchCustomer.custId = Customer Id  must be 7 characters.

Comment: Your ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bean is not well defined. You should not specify the complete name, just "messages", "_en_US.properties" is added by Spring when it does the search.

Try:

<bean id="messageSource"
     class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
     <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
 </bean>

Comment: still getting the same result. no change: Field error in object 'searchCustomerForm' on field 'custId': rejected value []; codes [NotEmpty.searchCustomerForm.custId,NotEmpty.custId,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [searchCustomerForm.custId,custId]; arguments []; default message [custId]]; default message [may not be empty]]

Comment: What are you using now in your properties file, SearchCustomer or SearchCustomerForm? It is looking for searchCustomerForm, because you are using @ModelAttribute("searchCustomerForm").

Comment: NotEmpty.SearchCustomer.custId = Customer Id  must be 7 characters.

Comment: No matter i use SerachCustomer or SearchCustomerForm, its not picking the message. Is there anything else am i going wrong?

Comment: true[Field error in object 'searchCustomerForm' on field 'custId': rejected value []; codes [NotEmpty.searchCustomerForm.custId,NotEmpty.custId,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [searchCustomerForm.custId,custId]; arguments []; default message [custId]]; default message [may not be empty]]

Comment: Are you sure you are using en_US locale?